# Allow the caller to use any pointer type (including smart pointers) with my Builder class?

Tags: c++, smart-pointers, builder

The standard way of implementing a Builder for `Foo` goes like this:

```
class Foo::Builder {
public:
  Builder& setBar(bool bar);
  ...
  Foo build() const;
};
```

Only when the caller tries to use this class with a smart pointer:

```
auto builder = std::make_shared<Foo::Builder>()->setProperty(...);
```

The builder cannot be used in this way, because `setProperty()` will return a reference to an object that will be destroyed by the time this statement completes executing. When the caller is calling `build()` in the same statement and the `Builder` class is never bound to a variable name, this doesn't matter.

However, in my application, I want to be able to do some configuration on a derived builder object, then pass it to the constructor of another class (which receives it as a pointer to a base type). I also want the caller to be able to decide the type of the pointer used. Could I do this by making `Foo::Builder` a template? Is there a better design pattern more suited for this? I'm open to ideas.

Comment: it would be the Factories class job to specify what types of pointers to a builder object it accepts, it isnt the `Builder`s buisness what someone uses to point to it

Comment: Looking at this line I would expect it to not compile, as you are accessing a pointer via dot notation instead of `->`

Comment: "*it's actually Foo::Builder&.*" Which is almost certainly a reference to an object that has been destroyed when the `shared_ptr` went out of scope.

Comment: can you show a [mcve] for that factory?

Comment: btw I dont really understand your example with `auto`. One would not expect `builder` to be a shared_ptr, but of the type that `setProperty` returns.

Comment: @UnholySheep thanks for pointing that out, I'll fix that.

Comment: @idclev463035818 What do you mean, "that factory"? There is no factory in this question. I use "a configurable Factory" as a simile.

Comment: @NicolBolas, that's a good point that I should mention, thank you! I'll refine the question to communicate what I'm looking for more clearly.

Comment: " then pass it to the constructor of another class (which receives it as a pointer to a base type)" i thought this "other class" is the factory

Comment: @idclev463035818 Ah, I see now. I'll add a MWE for the intended usage.

Comment: why you need to do `auto builder = std::make_shared<Foo::Builder>()->setProperty(...)` instead of `auto builder = std::make_shared<Foo::Builder>(); /* this IS the builder */ builder->setProperty(...);` ? The two parts of the question are unrelated, your point is very unclear

Comment: @Moia you could also write it that way, but the primary issue that I'm trying to get at is that `builder->setProperty(...)` will still return a `Foo::Builder&`. I'd like it to return a `std::shared_ptr<Foo::Builder>` or whatever pointer type _the caller_ chooses.

Comment: i am not sure if understood the question at all, but I was a bit bored and wrote an answer anyhow. Maybe it is somewhat related to your question ;)

Answer (score 0):

It isnt a class buisness to have control over what others use to point to instances. If that other class recieves some pointer to a `Builder` in its constructor, you can make the constructor a template:

```
struct OtherClass {
    template <typename T>
    OtherClass(T t) {
        t->setProperty();
    }
};
```

If you want to restrict `T` to types that have an `operator->` that returns a `Builder` you can either wait for C++20 concepts or write a typetrait that allows you to SFINAE:

```
template <typename P,typename T>
struct points_to : std::false_type {};

template <typename T>
struct points_to<T*,T> : std::true_type {};

template <typename P>
struct points_to<P,std::decay_t<decltype(std::declval<P>().operator->())>> : std::true_type {};
```

The constructor can then require that `points_to<T,Builder>` via:

```
struct AnotherClass {
    template <typename T,typename = std::enable_if_t<points_to<T,Builder>::value,void>>
    AnotherClass(T t){}
};
```

However, error messages won't be much better than for the non restricted template above. `static_assert` helps to get readable error messages:

```
struct AnotherClass {
    template <typename B>
    AnotherClass(B b){
        static_assert(points_to<B,Builder>::value,"b is not pointing to a Builder");
    }
};
```

[Live Example](https://godbolt.org/z/QZuJ_J)